# Unimplemented QColor error on compliation (C++)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm following Qt's [Qt for Beginners](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners) tutorial and for some reason I am getting a compilation error when trying to build the simplest example of a gui. It looks like it's failing on button creation because it thinks that qcolor is unimplemented(?). I just downloaded the latest Qt 5.14.0 and installed it today, so it's possible that something happened during the install?

This is what my project layout looks like:

```
build-new_qt_project-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_GCC_64bit-Debug:
    Makefile
new_qt_project:
    main.cpp
    new_qt_project.pro
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
    button.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

new_qt_project.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = new_qt_project

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And this is the output from trying to make it:

```
In file included from ../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qpixmap.h:45:0,
                 from ../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from ../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from ../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h:44,
                 from ../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QPushButton:1,
                 from ../new_qt_project/main.cpp:2:
../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qcolor.h: In constructor ‘constexpr QColor::QColor(int, int, int, int)’:
../../Qt5.14.0_2/5.14.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qcolor.h:79:18: sorry, unimplemented: use of the value of the object being constructed in a constant expression
              0) {}
                  ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I'm using the default (detected) kit to build it and it has the C++ compiler pointing to the one in /usr/bin, so I think that is correct. Is there something additional I've missed?

Comment: I think it's a bug of Qt 5.14, report it.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not opposed to doing so, but it seems that even the simplest test (as shown here) would have caught this bug, so I'm a little hesitant to assume it's a bug in Qt rather than something on my end

Comment: The code you provide is simple and I can easily see that it is correct, in addition to that I have answered a question on the same code base where I verify that the tutorial code is fully updated (at least for Qt 5.13.2). Although it seems strange to me it does not seem crazy that I have that bug that using constexpr for QColor was an introduction in Qt 5.14 that emphasizes my position.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

[Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTBUG-68012)

Comment: I'm not using MS Visual Studio (I'm on linux using Qt creator) and I'm initializing the QApplication first thing, so unless I'm misunderstanding, I think this might be a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

update your gcc. up to 4.9 !!!

i had this problem and i used gcc 4.8 and after update it to gcc-7 it is now correct